# VS Code + TypeScript + ESLint: How can I make linting errors less prominent than compiler errors?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

ESLint underlines errors in red. This is distracting, because compiler errors are more important than linting errors.

To me, linting issues might as well all be warnings anyway, but this is a little beside the point - the big deal is that compilation errors are unambiguously a bigger deal than any kind of linting issue, so they should be more prominent.

I am committed to producing lint-free code at the end of the day, but when you're in the middle of your changes and you have a mixture of linting and compilation issues, having the linting issues in red is extremely distracting.

What is the best way to achieve this? The best option I have found so far is to render the entire linting config and reconfigure everything as a warning, but this prevents me from keeping up to date with the linting rules that are maintained by others.

Also, I would still like CI to block on all linting issues, so re-configuring everything as a warning is suboptimal for this reason too.

Comment: SHort answer, no I don't there's a way to do that. But if it fails CI, then it's just as important as compile errors and deserve to be fixed as you go. You're asking for some severity between error and warning, and I don't think that exists.

Comment: > But if it fails CI, then it's just as important as compile errors and deserve to be fixed as you go.
@AlexWayne I'm genuinely curious how you see it this way. For example, unused variables happen all the time while you're writing code, they're expected. But you might think your code is otherwise fine, but if you see red, you know you've made some other - more important - mistake. If the unused variable is red, then it takes longer to see that mistake, and that slower feedback cycle slows you down.

Comment: I think if you have that many simultaneous linter warnings and compiler errors, then you're making a huge mess as you go. The well structured code that linters enforce isn't just a good idea for production code, it's a good idea because it helps you understand the flow of the code and work on it better. So I don't think you should let compile errors _or_ linter warning live long at all. Any error of either source deserves immediate attention, and if you address it immediately there are never enough for this to matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This can be configured in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
"eslint.rules.customizations": [
  {
    "rule": "*",
    "severity": "warn"
  }
],
```

OLD ANSWER: A clarification of "The best option I have found so far":

```bash
npx eslint --print-config src/index.ts >.eslintrc.json
```

(Replace `src/index.ts` with whatever representative source file makes sense for your project.)

This will create a config without an `"extends"` section but works the same as before by including an explicit configuration for every rule.

Now simply replace `"error"` with `"warn"` in `.eslintrc.json` using your preferred method.

You might want to restore the `"extends"` section from your previous config, that way if the eslint config projects you're following are updated, the new rules will show up. They'll be in red though, so you'll need to re-run this process (or manually reconfigure the new rules).

To make these warnings still fail on CI, add `--max-warnings 0` to the eslint command that runs on CI.